# The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to install or remove anything I get this error
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libgpg-error0: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installed
libgpg-error0:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.1.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installed
```

Comment: Have you push it with "sudo apt-get -f install" and/or "sudo aptitude -f install"?

Comment: yes i did, returns with the same error

Comment: i cant even install aptitude to deal with this, because whenever i try to install it, gives me the same issue

Comment: That's dependencies hell, and something error with your system. I guess you install .deb file via dpkg, let's try other solution;     sudo apt-get clean,     sudo apt-get install -fy,     sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb, and     sudo dpkg --configure -a.

Comment: cant get past sudo apt-get install -fy , its giving the same error

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=8611) and [this] (http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=972193)

Comment: but all i wanted to do was, install libimobiledevice which i am unable to install because dependancy is not satisfactory

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)